# Unable to add user to account. The user has reached their maximum number of Analytics accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-apps, google-analytics-api

Our company is currently developing an application that requires access to multiple Google Analytics accounts via a single Google Developer user. We were successfully able to add this user to approximately 100 Analytics accounts before we ran into the following error:

> *Unable to add user to account. The user has reached their maximum number of  Analytics accounts.*

This error has brought our work to a standstill. We would like to know if there is any work around we can implement or upgrade we can purchase in order to raise this account limit.

Comment: You can write GA Support, but the cost is high. My old company got around this by creating multiple accounts (dev1@gmail.com, dev2@gmail.com etc...)

Comment: Any reason why you haven't used Oauth2? I'm just wondering.

Comment: We are using Oauth 2.0. We aren't having any problems connecting to the GA API with our GD user. Our problem is rooted in our inability to add our GD user to any more GA accounts.

Comment: At the risk of sounding childish, the URL for this post is fantastic :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, we finally got in touch with someone from Google who was able to help us resolve our problem. The first thing we learned is that a single user can be associated with no more than 100 Google Analytics accounts. Next, we learned that there are only two ways around this limit, you can either raise the limit to 1,000 by purchasing Google Analytics Premium ($150,000 per year) or you use a different user for each block of 100 accounts.